# Laravel 8 middleware error in installation of multy tenancy - Undefined array key 0

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, middleware, multi-tenant

So i was installing multy tenancy for laravel following this doc: https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/quickstart

But when i needed to open tinker this error occurs:

```
  ErrorException 

  Undefined offset: 0

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1329
    1325▕         if ($method === 'middleware') {
    1326▕             return (new RouteRegistrar($this))->attribute($method, is_array($parameters[0]) ? $parameters[0] : $parameters);
    1327▕         }
    1328▕ 
  ➜ 1329▕         return (new RouteRegistrar($this))->attribute($method, $parameters[0]);
    1330▕     }
    1331▕ }
    1332▕ 

      +3 vendor frames 
  4   app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php:26
      Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::__call()

      +7 vendor frames 
  12  [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}()
```

Why is this error happening? I couldn't find any answers in the internet that matches my problem.
My laravel version is 8.52.0 and Php 7.4.28.

Edit:

I discovered the error actually occurs in this function of the RouteServiceProvider:

```
    public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting(); // <-- this one

    $this->routes(function () {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();
        $this->mapWebRoutes();
    });

}
```

If i comment it tinker opens normally, can i not call this function or would it cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

It is used as a limit for per API request sent per user.
If you remove that a user can send many API requests which may overload the application.

I properly set up the package by following instructions. I think you miss some instructions. [Please the the image for instructions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/narmq.jpg)